# Ввести массив длинных целых беззнаковых чисел. определить цифру (или цифры), которая чаще всего повторялась в этих числах.С указателями

Tags: c, указатели

> С клавиатуры ввести массив длинных целых беззнаковых чисел. определить
> цифру (или цифры), которая чаще всего повторялась в этих числах.
>
> Подсказка:
> целесообразно создать отдельный массив, в который записывать количество повторений
> каждой из десятичных цифр.

Comment: Вы хоть сами пробовали это сделать?

Comment: Цифры числа получать умеете?

Answer (score 2):

Почему так сложно хотя бы начать? Сейчас 20 декабря. Конец семестра. И не ужели за целый семестр ничего не выучили?

Пойдем по порядку:

1. Нужно создать массив под длинные целые беззнаковые числа. И тут в есть 2 варианта

   1. Использовать **статический** массив.

      Для начало нужно почитать про [них](https://prog-cpp.ru/c-massiv/). Вы задаёте массиву такой размер, который вряд ли будет заполнять пользователь. (Например `100` или `128` элементов).

      Далее вы просите пользователя ввести кол-во чисел, которые он собирается вводить (очевидно это число должно быть строго меньше размера массива).
   2. Использовать **динамический** массив.

      Так же читаете про [них](https://prog-cpp.ru/c-alloc/).

      Сначала вы просите пользователя ввести кол-во чисел, а далее выделяете память под введенное кол-во чисел.

      Так же нужно не забыть освободить память, чтобы не было утечки.
2. После `1` пункта у нас есть инициализированный массив `arr` длинной `size`.

   Далее вы просите пользователя ввести `size` чисел, которые заносите в массив. Ссылку на циклы я скидывать не буду, а то это слишком уже.
3. Потом, как и в первом пункте вы создаёте уже точно статический массив длинной `10`, например `digits`. (т.к. цифр `10`).
4. Далее самое важное вы пишите функцию, которая принимает длинное целое беззнаковое число, а так же статический массив `digits`, в который после завершения работы функции, будет записаны кол-во каждой цифры.

   Например так: `void calcDigits(unsigned long int num, int* digits)`

   Сама реализация функции довольна проста, очевидно я не буду писать её код вам, но **подсказка** нужно использовать деление с остатком на 10 для получения последней цифры, и деление на 10, чтобы перейти к следующей цифре с конца.
5. И самое простое это в массиве `digits` найти максимальное число `max_count`. После чего в последний раз пройти по массиву `digits` и если элемент равен `max_count`, то выводим эту цифру в консоль.

Как же просто все оказывается :)

P.S. Да мне проще было просто скинуть код, который еще до вопроса был написан, но ...